# Text width minitoc in two column document

Tags: two-column, minitoc

I would like to have a minitoc in my two column document, utilising the full width of one column. How do I achieve this?

See attached a MWE and the red box in the figure below which indicates the space which is currently not used.

Thanks in advance, Thomas.

MWE illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\mtcsetrules{secttoc}{off}
\mtcsettitle{secttoc}{}
\mtcsetoffset{secttoc}{-3em}
\dosecttoc

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{This is the first section}
    \lipsum[66]
    \secttoc
    
    \subsection{Part 1 this is the first subsection}
    \lipsum[66]
    
    \subsection{Part 2 this is the second subsection}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: red box illustrating unused area]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\mtcsetrules{secttoc}{off}
\mtcsettitle{secttoc}{}
\mtcsetoffset{secttoc}{-1em} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\stcindent}{-1ex}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\dosecttoc

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{This is the first section}
    \lipsum[66]
    \secttoc
    
    \subsection{Part 1 this is the first subsection}
    \lipsum[66]
    
    \subsection{Part 2 this is the second subsection}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```